# Load contextual config in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app which uses country wise config files. The structure of the config files is same but values are different for different countries.

I have created a directory for each country in resources directory and placed that country's config file there.

Based on the country code passed in request parameters, I want to use the corresponding config file. What's the spring boot idiomatic way to achieve this (Apart from manually loading the yaml config files using something like snakeyaml)?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can acheive by creating bean for `MessageSource`,`LocaleResolver` and `LocaleChangeInterceptor` bean and then add `LocaleChangeInterceptor` to `InterceptorRegistry` like this:

```
@Configuration
    public class CountryConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

        @Bean
        public MessageSource messageSource() {
            ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
            messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:country-conf/country");
            messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
            messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600);
            return messageSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
            SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
            slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
            return slr;
        }

        @Bean
        public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
            LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
            lci.setParamName("country");
            return lci;
        }

        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
        }
    }
```

And then create a folder-`country-conf` in `resources` folder . Inside this folder create properties file which will have your configuration. Ex:

**country.properties (Default)**

```
country.name=United states
```

**country_fr.properties**

```
country.name=France
```

`country.properties` is the default properties if no country is sent in parameter and if you send `country=fr` in parameter then it will look for `country_fr.properties` file.

Now create a service that will get value from these properties file based on country parameter

```
@Service
public class CountryService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    public String getMessage(String code) {
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        return this.messageSource.getMessage(code, null, locale);
    }
}
```

To test this autowire country service

```
@Autowired
CountryService countryService;
```

And then call getMessage method

```
countryService.getMessage("country.name");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring `@Profile` for each country. See [examples](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/) and [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).

> Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application
>   configuration and make it only available in certain environments. Any
>   @Component or @Configuration can be marked with @Profile to limit when
>   it is loaded:

You can add Profile on run time:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("za");
```

Comment: As far as I understand, you have to tell spring boot which profile to load at start up (e.g. dev, staging, prod etc.). In my case, it's request based e.g. /getData?countryCode=za, /getData?countryCode=in etc and I have to use appropriate config files (za/config.yaml and in/config.yaml) to serve each request. Is using profiles the right approach for this?

Comment: You can add it programmatic: `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("za");`